# how do i let UI thread to execute a command when im in some thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, ui-thread

how do i let UIthread to execute a command when im in some thread
the code below is called by a thread but the line i want to run in UIthread .. doesn't work if i called it like that ..
the form lag a little and the process fan got fast like it's in infinity loop.. then it gives me an error "stackoverflowexception"

my application is a file manager .. (copy, cut, paste, new folder..etc) .. and **dirRecursive(string path)** .. shows me the files and folders in a listView **with its icons** so every time i do something like (new folder or paste) i have to call **dirRecursive** to update the listView

note:

it works excellent before i tried to execute **PasteFromCopy** with a thread ..

it works excellent when i remove the **dirRecursive(..)** line from the paste method .. but i need to update **listview** automatically after the paste is done .. that why i have to call it from **PasteFromCopy** but using UIThread

if i used UIThread to PASTE then the form will lag when a file is being copyied .. you know

please help :) thanks in advance

```
private void PasteFromCopy(object dest)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in copiedItems)
        {
            string _dest = (string)dest;
            string itemName = item.Text;
            string itemPath = item.ToolTipText;
            string itemDest = Path.Combine(_dest, itemName);
            if (IsFolder(itemPath))
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(itemDest))
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show(itemName + " is already exists .. Do you want to overwrite it and its all contents?"
                        , "Overwrite", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        CopyDirectory(itemPath, itemDest, true);
                    }
                }
                else
                    CopyDirectory(itemPath, itemDest, false);
            }
            else
            {
                if (File.Exists(itemDest))
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show(itemName + " is already exists .. Do you want to overwrite it?"
                    , "Overwrite", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        InfoLabel("Copying " + itemName + " ...");
                        File.Copy(itemPath, itemDest, true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    InfoLabel("Copying " + itemName + " ...");
                    File.Copy(itemPath, itemDest, false);
                }
            }
            InfoLabel("Paste done.");

            dirRecursive(currAddress);   // here is line i need to execute from UIthread
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: Please do not prefix your question titles with c# or the like; that is what the tags are for.

Comment: the title of the link that you just gave me had C# .. !!
and this's to update a property of a control .. not to call a function that i have to run it in UIThread.. please read my question before you answer

Comment: i need a way to call a simple function in UI thread.. how do i do that dispatcher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing this line

```
dirRecursive(currAddress);
```

with

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    Action a = ()=>dirRecursive(currAddress);
    Invoke(a);
}
```

This is assuming you're using WinForms and not WPF, you haven't specified. Also 'InvokeRequired' and 'Invoke' are both members of a System.Windows.Forms.Control so your PasteFromCopy would need to be a method on your form.